# Swift, is there a way to align items at the end of a text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an issue with Swift, I can't align a label at the end of a title, I've tried in different ways but without success

[This is the result I get and what I'd like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgMs.png)

```
 Label {
        
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud mihi a te nimium festinanter dictum videtur")

    } icon: {
        
            Text("  TEST  ")
                .background(Color.orange)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        
        
    } .labelStyle(RightIconLabelStyle())
```

```
struct RightIconLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
            configuration.title
            configuration.icon
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried also with 2 Text() elements, but it gives me error, you can't have a different background color property for a specific Text()

`Text("This is a test title") + Text ("TEST").background(Color.orange)`

Is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am not sure what you are trying to do with your code. A `Label` takes a `Text` and an `Image`. You can't put `Text("  TEST  ")` in for the icon and expect it to show anything.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you, you're right but I didn't know what to use, strangely it renders also the text, I've posted the screenshot, basically I need a title and append at the end another text with a different background color, `This is a title (featured)` something like that where featured must have a different background color than the title

Comment: It's easy to solve if it would be ok to change the foreground color instead of the background color.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'd need the background, appending Text() + Text() I saw you can change the foreground color but not the background, weird. Unfortunately I really need the background in another color

Comment: The reason for this is that there is a version of .foreground that returns a Text but that doesn't exist for .background

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, I'm new to swift and it's a bit complicated, especially when you have to mix swift and uikit things. If you have an idea, what would you do to solve my problem? I tried also creating an image for the label, but unfortunately I need the text to be dinamic so it's not really a solution either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to simply make "Test" an `AttributedString` like this:

```
struct AttributedStringView: View {
    var test: AttributedString {
        var attText = AttributedString("Test")
        attText.foregroundColor = .white
        attText.backgroundColor = .orange
                return attText
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Illud mihi a te nimium festinanter dictum videtur") +
            Text(" ") +
            Text(test)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Almost perfect, is there a way to set a corner radius for attText? I'd need a pill shape for the background

Comment: @vamp: Do not Hostage the answer for solving another issue first the original issue get solved! If you want you can make new question for that as well! If the answer solve the issue simply accept it.

Comment: @swiftPunk the original image does show rounded corners. Vamp, that is not simple, but I will point you here: [Background with rounded corners in UITextView](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/background-with-rounded-corners-in-uitextview-1c095c708d14). That is the same basic `AttributedString` we are using here. You may have to open it in a private browser window to get past the "you have reached your view limit` guard on the site.